# Ошибка приведения типов при сортировке модели

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть приложение на asp.net. Решил написать интерфейс и наследуемый от него класс сортировки любой модели какая к нему придёт.
И всё бы нормально получаю отсортированную модель, но когда пытаюсь выплюнуть во view начинаются проблемы.
Interface:

```
public interface IModelSort<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetModelSort(IEnumerable<T> model, Func<T, dynamic> predSort, string typeSort);
}
```

Класс наследуемый от этого интерфейса:

```
public class ModelSort<T> : IModelSort<T> where T : class
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetModelSort(IEnumerable<T> model, Func<T, dynamic> predSort, string typeSort = "Asc")
    {
        if (typeSort == "Asc")
            return model.OrderBy(predSort);
        else
            return model.OrderByDescending(predSort);
    }
}
```

Далее у меня есть класс называемый UnitOfBusiness и в нём создаются экземпляры всех классов бизнесс логики, включая этот:

```
public class UnitOfBusiness
{
    private ModelSort<dynamic> modelSorting;

    public ModelSort<dynamic> ModelSorting
    {
        get
        {
            if (modelSorting == null)
                modelSorting = new ModelSort<dynamic>();
            return modelSorting;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sort, int page = 1)
{
    IEnumerable<Car> cars = unitOfWOrk.Cars.GetAll();
    var result = unitOfBusiness.ModelSorting.GetModelSort(cars, i => i.Price).ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```

И наконец view:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<AutoStore.Domain.Core.Car>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h1>Каталог автомобилей</h1>

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
</style>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Марка", "Index")
            </th>
            <th>Модель</th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Цена", "Index")
            </th>
            <th>Количество на складе</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Cars as List<AutoStore.Domain.Core.Car>)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Mark.MarkName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.CarModel.ModelName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Price)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Count)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

В итоге на view вылетает ошибка:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[AutoStore.Domain.Core.Car]'.

Пробовал как должно быть, передавать модель во вью с помощью

```
 result.ToPagedList(page, 8)
```

Тот же самый результат. Пробовал из ошибки получить пользу и принимать на view в pagedlist вместо модели, object, тогда вылетает другая ошибка.

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

И такая же ошибка вылетает если передавать список отсортированных машин через ViewBag. Подскажите пожалуйста что можно сделать? Уже всю голову сломал.

Comment: какого типа у вас результат `return View(result);` и что вы ожидаете во вьюхе  `@model PagedList.IPagedList<AutoStore.Domain.Core.Car>`

Comment: А что вы хотели собственно? Вам честно говорится, что у вас `List<System.Object>` когда вью требует `PagedList<Car>`

Comment: `Func<T, dynamic> predSort` не надо везде где попало пихать dynamic, он для крайних случаев, вы и без него можете обойтись.

Comment: @tym32167 а как? Я же могу по всяким полям сортировать и не знаю что туда придёт?

Comment: @AK я хочу вывести отсортированный список автомобилей на view в таблицу.

Comment: сделай тип сортировки перечисление и не обазательным парметром и если он не пердан то соритруектся по умолчанию то есмть во возрастанию

Comment: типа enum `SortType { Asc,Desc }`  public interface IModelSort<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetModelSort(IEnumerable<T> model, Func<T, dynamic> predSort, SortType? typeSort);
}

Comment: Если вы хотите сортированный список авто, то у вас во вью написано правильно. Осталось передать во вью правильный тип. Где-то у вас должен быть каст к PagedList<Car>

Comment: @AK я писал в вопросе что пробовал кастануть к пейджлисту и даже привёл пример кода, ошибка та же, говорит что там обджект

Comment: Я не знаю, почему и как не скастовалось. Но попробуйте просто навести курсор на var и посмотреть, какой у него тип. Если PageList<Car> - значит правильно скастовали, если другой - то нет.

Comment: @AK хорошо как буду у компьютера погляжу, и отпишу обязательно

Comment: @AK попробовал посмотреть к чему привёлся тип. Вот код которым привёл `var result = unitOfBusiness.ModelSorting.GetModelSort(cars, i => i.Price).ToPagedList(page, 8);` а тип получился `{PagedList.PagedList<object>}`

Comment: @AK странно что не pagedlist<car> но даже если так, я пробовал на view вместо car писать object, выходит ошибка что ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: @tym32167 посмотрите пожалуйста мои последние комментарии в вашем ответе, подскажите пожалуйста, а то не могу понять немного.

Comment: @tym32167 как сможете, отзовитесь пожалуйста, а то уже всю голову сломал над тем что вы имели в виду `если вам в этом классе модель нужна как свойство или поле, то да. Если вы вместо свойства напишете метод для создания модели, то все параметры передаёте в этот метод, тогда можете иметь один uob, и создавайте в нем хоть сколько моделей`. Не как не получается воспроизвести.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберем dynamic

```
public interface IModelSort<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetModelSort<K>(IEnumerable<T> model, Func<T,K> sortFunction, bool ask);
}

public class ModelSort<T> : IModelSort<T> where T : class
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetModelSort<K>(IEnumerable<T> model, Func<T,K> acessor, bool ask)
    {
        return ask ? model.OrderBy(acessor) : model.OrderByDescending(acessor);
    }
}
```

ваш UOB

```
public class UnitOfBusiness<T> where T : class
{
    private ModelSort<T> modelSorting;

    public ModelSort<T> ModelSorting
    {
        get
        {   
            if (modelSorting == null)
                modelSorting = new ModelSort<T>();
            return modelSorting;
        }
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
public ActionResult Index(string sort, int page = 1) 
{ 
    IEnumerable<Car> cars = unitOfWOrk.Cars.GetAll(); 
    var result = unitOfBusiness.ModelSorting.GetModelSort(cars, c=>c.Price, true).ToList(); 
    return View(result.ToPagedList(page, 8)); 
}
```

ЗЫ Писал на тапке, компилировал в уме, это просто пример, как уйти от dynamic

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88395/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167------).